# Bootstrap Accordion Icons not changing Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to Add bootstrap Accordion to my project but its not working.... what is the problem with my code i have added below with JavaScript.

I am also including following files in my project.
Thanks in Advance.
Regards.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2" style="font-size:large;color:black;opacity:0.8;border-radius:05px;min-height:inherit;">
            <div id="accordion" class="panel-group">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a href="#fabricBody" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-up"></span>
                                Fabric
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="fabricBody" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Wash n Wear</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Cotton</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Silk</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Stone Wash</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a href="#priceBody" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span>
                              Price

                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="priceBody" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">3120 to 4680</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">4681 to 6240</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Above 6240</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a href="#menDressesBody" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span>Men Dresses

                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="menDressesBody" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Classic Sherwani</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Modern Sherwani</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Prince Suit</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Mens Shalwar Kameez</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">WaistCoat Suits</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Mens Turbans</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
        </div>



<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
                $(this).parent().find('.glyphicon-collapse-down').removeClass('.glyphicon-collapse-down')
            }).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
                $(this).parent().find('..glyphicon-collapse-up').removeClass('.glyphicon-collapse-up').addClass('.glyphicon-collapse-down');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: What does “it's not working” mean exactly? Please describe the problem in more details, what do you expect to happen, what is actually happening, what errors are you getting in the browser's JavaScript console, etc.

Comment: `..glyphicon-collapse-up` won't work

Comment: l expect that the glypicons should change dynamically..... I mean my Jquery script is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to change the accordion icons I would suggest to use:

- [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) in order to change icons from down to up and vice versa,
- [show.bs.collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) event
- [hide.bs.collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) event

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse hide.bs.collapse', function () {
      $(this).closest('.panel').find('.panel-heading .glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-collapse-down glyphicon-collapse-up')
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2" style="font-size:large;color:black;opacity:0.8;border-radius:05px;min-height:inherit;">
            <div id="accordion" class="panel-group">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a href="#fabricBody" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span>
                                Fabric
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="fabricBody" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Wash n Wear</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Cotton</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Silk</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Stone Wash</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a href="#priceBody" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span>
                                Price

                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="priceBody" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">3120 to 4680</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">4681 to 6240</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Above 6240</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a href="#menDressesBody" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span>Men Dresses

                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="menDressesBody" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Classic Sherwani</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Modern Sherwani</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Prince Suit</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Mens Shalwar Kameez</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">WaistCoat Suits</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Mens Turbans</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dear... Your code works for me. i used toggle class in other way. Again thanks for helping... :)

Comment: @AsadMarwat I am glad hear that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can look for the previous element and find the span with a class of `.glyphicon`.
Then simply add or remove the up and down classes.

Here is an example.

```js
$('.collapse')
  .on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
  $(this).prev().find('.glyphicon')
    .removeClass('glyphicon-collapse-down')
    .addClass('glyphicon-collapse-up')
})
  .on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
  $(this).prev().find('.glyphicon')
    .removeClass('glyphicon-collapse-up')
    .addClass('glyphicon-collapse-down')
});
```

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2" style="font-size:large;color:black;opacity:0.8;border-radius:05px;min-height:inherit;">
      <div id="accordion" class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a href="#fabricBody" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-up"></span>
                Fabric
              </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="fabricBody" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Wash n Wear</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cotton</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Silk</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Stone Wash</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a href="#priceBody" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span>
                Price

              </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="priceBody" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">3120 to 4680</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">4681 to 6240</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Above 6240</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a href="#menDressesBody" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span>Men Dresses

              </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="menDressesBody" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Classic Sherwani</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Modern Sherwani</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Prince Suit</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mens Shalwar Kameez</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">WaistCoat Suits</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mens Turbans</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this link. http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/3gYa3/

Bootstrap accordion using only CSS

```
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle:after {
/* symbol for "opening" panels */
font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';  /* essential for enabling glyphicon */
content: "\e114";    /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
float: right;        /* adjust as needed */
color: grey;         /* adjust as needed */
}
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
/* symbol for "collapsed" panels */
content: "\e080";    /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
}
```